# What is the `using` keyword in Haxe?

Tags: using, haxe

I often see people use the keyword `using` in their Haxe code. It seem to go after the `import` statements.

For example, I found this is a code snippet:

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Type;
using haxe.macro.Tools;
using Lambda;
```

What does it do and how does it work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "using" mixin feature of Haxe is also referred as "[static extension](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html)". It's a great syntactic sugar feature of Haxe; they can have a positive effect on code readability.

A static extension allows pseudo-extending existing types without modifying their source. In Haxe this is achieved by declaring a static method with a *first argument of the extending type* and then bringing the defining class into context through the `using` keyword.

Take a look at this example:

```
using Test.StringUtil;

class Test {
    static public function main() {
        // now possible with because of the `using`
        trace("Haxe is great".getWordCount());

        // otherwise you had to type
        // trace(StringUtil.getWordCount("Haxe is great"));
    }
}

class StringUtil {
    public static inline function getWordCount(value:String) {
        return value.split(" ").length;
    }
}
```

> Run this example here: http://try.haxe.org/#C96B7

**More in the Haxe Documentation:**

- [Haxe static extensions](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html) in the Haxe Manual
- [Haxe static extensions](http://code.haxe.org/tag/static-extension.html) tagged articles in the Haxe Code Cookbook

Comment: Is it faster to use 'using' over 'import'?

Comment: @c.c. They are completely different thing